# Bootstrap 4.2.1: subfolder page crash Navbar

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have an ASP.NET website using Masterpages and some pages are being loaded from a specific subfolder. **Using Bootstrap 4.0 everything were ok.**

But now, using Bootstrap 4.2.1, when I jump to one of these pages, the NavBar options which contain submenus using `class="nav-link dropdown-toogle"` are broken.

When I put the mouse over the dropdown menu, no options appear below (the related menu is not loaded/shown).

I investigate why it's occurring and I saw that the HREF (which if pointing originally to #) is showing now "../#" and Chrome sends the following message:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on
>   'Document': '../#' is not a valid selector.

All the remaining code is exactly the same.

The code is shown below:

```
<li Class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a runat="server" Class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="AdmFuncs" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Arquivos</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" >
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/AdminActions/Categorias.aspx">Categorias</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/AdminActions/Fabricantes.aspx">Fabricantes</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/AdminActions/Recepcao.aspx">E-mail Receptor</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I go to the subfolder page, the code appears like below:

```
<li Class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a runat="server" Class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="../#"
```

**NOTE ABOVE THE ../# in HREF**

Interesting to note that:

1. Command options that are not using any dropdown option, have **HREF="../"** but Bootstrap understand them normally.
2. Command options which have dropdown options (like the above), have **HREF="../#"** (instead just "#") and Bootstrap sends an error to DOM and does not open the related menu.

Any tip to solve it?
I appreciate in advance.

## UPDATE

Talking with support they had recommended to use `data-target=#` or even put an ID into the `dropdown-toogle` class control and reference it with `data-target`.

No success at all.
Seeing the DOM I can see that, when the content page is loaded (and it is on a subfolder), the HREF changes and seems to paralyse Bootstrap...

## UPDATE-2

I made a test moving all pages from the subfolder to the main folder (a not accepted solution by the client) and everything functions like a charm. The problem is related with Bootstrap 4.2.1 + ASP Materpages + Pages in SubFolder.

And as recommended below, I took off the HREF=# to a try... no success at all.

## UPDATE-3

Siava had recommeded to remove **runat=server** and change some links, ensuring that he is simulating there either the problem as the solution. But, unfortunetly, I had the following results:

[image: Inspecting menu after access sub-page]

You can see above that the problem with HREF had disappeared BUT the problem persisted.

If we analyze the errors of Chrome, we see this:

[image: Chrome Inspect LOG]

If you had faced and solved this problem, I will appreciate a lot to inform here.

Hugs!

Comment: Try Bootstrap 3?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.0 was functioning very well...  I don't see reason to downgrade to 3.

Comment: I'm not sure about any newer version of ASPNET, but most versions' templates were targeting Bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 4 was known to break the nav. Very easy to downgrade to v3 with Nuget, and change back to 4 again if you can rule that out.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. If I add `../#` to the first link in `<li class="nav-item dropdown">` it still works. Even if I add your `li` with the dropdown in my own code it still works. This would suggest some other javascript code is messing things up. What happens if you rename the `id="AdmFuncs"`? I used `v4.1.3`

Comment: Nothing. I tried to reference ID with no success at all. This code is in a MASTERPAGE of an ASP.NET project. As I said above, Bootstrap 4.1.3 FUNCTIONS NORMALLY - the problem is focused into 4.2.1 and I cannot downgrade this version in the system due to other systems/apps in my client.

Comment: @DavidBS i deleted my answer so someone can provide something more accurate

Comment: @DavidBS what happened when you removed the `href="#"`? How have you updated your Bootstrap version?

Comment: @Siavas, see below ... exactly the same behaviour. I update my Bootstrap from within Visual Studio, since version 4.2.1 is a "stable version".

Answer (score 3):

Might even be a feature :)

Try removing server-side processing from your dropdown anchors, as using it seems to cause the parser to think "#" is a resource at the level of your MasterPage, thus prepending it with `../` to go up a level.

`<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="AdmFuncs" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Arquivos</a>`

This would work as currently you do not seem to have any server-side processing on that tag. Should that happen in the future, you may use `NavigateUrl="#"` instead:

`<a runat="server" Class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" NavigateUrl="#" id="AdmFuncs" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Arquivos</a>`

Hope this helps!

---

Update:

Have just been able to reproduce your issue (dropdown in master page, browsing page from subfolder, Bootstrap 4.2.1) and have fixed it with the following:

```
<li Class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="AdmFuncs" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="AdmFuncsDropDown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Arquivos</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="AdmFuncsDropDown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" >
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/AdminActions/Categorias.aspx">Categorias</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/AdminActions/Fabricantes.aspx">Fabricantes</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/AdminActions/Recepcao.aspx">E-mail Receptor</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

If this does not work try clearing the cache as well (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), otherwise there is some other part or error that makes the error persist.

Comment: Thanks Siava but no sucess at all. Let me explain:  1- NavigateUrl is not recognized as HTML keyword for VS2017. Anyway, I tested with/without this keyword.  2- Even removing "runat=server" the link behaves exactly as above, but acting like a Boostrap button: the word is black with background transparent and at click, changes itself to a "primary button".

Comment: And it's not a feature but a bug with ASP Masterpage and pages within subfolders. See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903 .

Comment: No worries @DavidBS the first line was just meant as a joke. Thanks for the link, I have updated my answer with a snippet that you can try, both with `href="#"` and without it altogether.

Comment: Thanks Siava but still not working (see the *first UPDATE* in the question). I'm using VS2017 and Chrome 71.0.3578 and the system is set to .NET 4.6.1.  All combinations and tips like exposed by you and throught the above link by Boostrap tean was tested, unsuccessfully.

Comment: @DavidBS Just to make sure you have cleared the cache as explained in the answer? We actually have also the same versions for all the three mentioned, and it is very unlikely this problem is caused by two things at once. Have you also tried running in a different browser?

Comment: Try copy-pasting my code as it has other additions beside `#data-*` attributes.

Comment: Siava, I copied/pasted the code before. Let me show you what I have here in the new **UPDATE-3** I will write in minutes...

Comment: And yes, all tests are "cache-clean"...  Are you understanding now WHY this problem really sucks?  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187184/discussion-between-siavas-and-david-bs).

Comment: Sorry Siava, I can't - managing team and working hard on this project. Thank you so much for your help but I really can't do it...

Comment: No worries @DavidBS, I know how it goes! The only two things you could try are cleaning the solution and rebuilding it and testing in another browser. Best of luck with your work!

Comment: I did it (clean) many times. If I copy pages from subfolder to main folder OR if I regress back to Bootstrap 4.1.3 everything goes 100%. The folder is being accessed normally through 4.1.3 ...  Weird really. See the GIT above and you will see many people with different scenarios complaining about the same behavior.